# How to drop duplicates in column with respect to values in another column in pandas?

Tags: python

I have a database with person names and the date of their visit. I need to remove duplicated rows in "Visit_date" column with respect to each person in another column. I have a very big database, so I need a working code. I've spent several days trying to do this, but no result. Here is a sample:

```
      Person      Visit_date
  0     John     11.09.2020
  1     John     11.09.2020
  2     John     11.08.2020
  3     Andy     11.07.2020
  4     Andy     11.09.2020
  5     Andy     11.09.2020
  6     George   11.09.2020
  7     George   11.09.2020
  8     George   11.07.2020
  9     George   11.07.2020
```

The code should return:

```
            Person   Visit_date
      0     John     11.09.2020
      1     John     11.08.2020
      2     Andy     11.07.2020
      3     Andy     11.09.2020
      4     George   11.09.2020
      5     George   11.07.2020
```

Comment: Have you tried `df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this method. It removes all the duplicates without considering values in "Person" column. It gives me:

    `Person   Visit_date  
      0     John     11.09.2020  
      1     John     11.08.2020  
      2     Andy     11.07.2020`

So it removes all the duplicates.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the top three lines of your expected output? When I do `df.drop_duplicates()` on your sample input data, it returns your desired output. Besides, you can update your question with what you have tried and post the unexpected output instead of using comment section ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope** this help you. Using `df.drop_duplicates()` then `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person" :['John','John','John','Andy','Andy','Andy','George','George','George','George'],"Visit_date" :['11.09.2020','11.09.2020','11.08.2020','11.07.2020','11.09.2020','11.09.2020','11.09.2020','11.09.2020','11.07.2020','11.07.2020']})

df=df.drop_duplicates()
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

**[Result]:**

> ```
>     Person  Visit_date
> 0    John  11.09.2020
> 1    John  11.08.2020
> 2    Andy  11.07.2020
> 3    Andy  11.09.2020
> 4  George  11.09.2020
> 5  George  11.07.2020
> ```

Comment: @BeketKassymbekov, Your are welcome. So, you can checkmark it as "Accepted Answer", https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer